# How to only show MediaElement while it has something in it?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, mediaelement

I have a Message Board ListView which 3 types of messages can be posted to it - Text, Photo and Video.

Whenever a message is submitted, a MessageModel is created depending on the type. All type will have Sender and Message Text, photo will have PhotoPath and video will have VideoPath.

```
public string Sender { get; set; }
public string MessageText { get; set; }
public string ImagePath { get; set; }
public string VideoPath { get; set; }
```

Here is my XAML for the message board -

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
            <ListView x:Name="MessageFeed" SelectionMode="None" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Label Text="Message Board" TextColor="{StaticResource AppTextColor}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="24" Padding="0,25" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MessageBackgroundColor}"  Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MessageBackgroundColor}" Margin="10,5,0,10">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Sender, StringFormat='{}Posted by {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource AppTextColor}" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="25,0" />
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <xct:MediaElement Source="{Binding VideoPath}" AutoPlay="False" ShowsPlaybackControls="True" HeightRequest="100" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding MessageText}" TextColor="{StaticResource AppTextColor}" FontSize="14"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

My issue is with the MediaElement through Xamarin.CommunityToolkit (2.0.5). The element needs to have a height value set otherwise it will never show - even if there is a video. However if I set a height value, this then shows on every list view item as a big black box where there is no video.

Does anybody know how to only show the MediaElement HeightRequest while VideoPath contains a value? I can't use x:Name to target it because it's inside a ListView and I'm totally stumped for how to proceed.

I'm also open to any alternative way to show a video in Xamarin.

Appreciate any help

Comment: bind `IsVisible` to the `VideoPath` property using [IsNotNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/isnotnulloremptyconverter) converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason has pointed it out, you can bind `IsVisible` to the `VideoPath` which means that if you don't assign the video path to the `MediaElement`, the `MediaElement` would be invisible(no big black box).

```
<ContentPage.Resources> 
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <xct:IsNotNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="IsNotNullOrEmptyConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<xct:MediaElement 
Source="{Binding VideoPath}" 
AutoPlay="False" 
ShowsPlaybackControls="True" 
HeightRequest="100" 
IsVisible = "{Binding VideoPath,Converter= {StaticResource IsNotNullOrEmptyConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks to you both, appreciate the example too. Never considered Binding to anything other than Text before, definitely makes sense!